# Why $C_{n}(A) + C_{n}(X-W)$ isn't a direct sum?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'm confusing with the definition : 
First : Let two abelian group $A,B$ then we know the set $A \times B$ ( Cartersian product , also call weak product if infinite sets ) is same as their direct sum .

If we have a collection of set $\left \{ G_{i} \right \}_{i \in I}$ , then their weak product is the subgroup of Cartersian product ( $G = \prod_{i \in I} G_{i}$ ) consisting of all element $g \in G$ such that each coordinate $g_{i} \in G_{i}$ is the identity element of $G_{i}$ for all except a finite number of induces $i$ .

Second : Let $S$ be a set :

$$S = \left \{ x_{i} , i \in I  \right \}$$

Let :

$$F_{i} = \left \{ x_{i}^{n} , n \in Z \right \}$$

Then we know the weark product of the $F_{i}$ is a free abelian group on the set $S$ .

Now a continuous map $T : [0,1]^{n} \to X$ is called a singular cube in $X$ . Let $C_{n}(X)$ denotes the free abelian group with basis is the set of all nondegenerate singular cubes .( nondegenerate means this cube is depend on all its coordinate ) , let a cover of topology space $X$ is $\partial =  \left \{  A , B \right \}$ . A singular cube is said to be small of order $\partial$ if its image is contained in a set of colletion $\partial$ , the symbol $C_{n}(X,\partial)$ is the free abelian group with basis is all of nondegenerate singular cube in $X$ which also is said to be small order of $\partial$

I tried to prove  that $C_{n}(X , \partial) = C_{n}(A)C_{n}(B)$ and a more question is " why $C_{n}(A)C_{n}(B)$ isn't a direct sum " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is inconsistent with the body of the question, but I think your question is equivalent to why

$$\Delta^{\mathbf{U}}(X)=\Delta(A)+\Delta(B)$$ 
is not a direct sum, where $\mathbf{U}=\{A,B\}$ is a cover of $X$ and $\Delta^{\mathbf{U}}$ is the free abelian group generated by the $\mathbf{U}$-small simplexes (which means that the simplexes have range inside $A$ or $B$ - the terminology and exposition can be seen in Bredon).

This is simply due to the fact that there can be simplexes in $A \cap B$ . For instance, let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $A=(-3,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$, $B=(-\infty, 3) \times \mathbb{R}$. Then, $\sigma: \Delta_1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by the inclusion is in $\Delta(A)$ and $\Delta(B)$. However, direct summands must have empty intersection.

Comment: (The only difference is that the question is about cubic homology, which is essentially the same thing.)